# pdftk: PHP Fatal error: Class 'mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf' not found in

Tags: php, composer-php, pdftk

I have a project in Slim framework. There are multiple composer packages. Now, I have added https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk to fill PDF but I'm getting PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf' not found in... What is wrong with my code?

composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
     "dibi/dibi": "^3.0",
     "slim/slim": "^3.7.0",
     "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
     "jbroadway/urlify":"^1.1.0",
     "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode":"^1.5.1",
     "gopay/payments-sdk-php":"^1.2.3",
     "mikehaertl/php-pdftk":"^0.4.2"
   }
}
```

in my ./config/config.php there is:

```
 define('PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
 require_once PATH."/vendor/autoload.php";
```

and in my ./methods/controller.php:

```
 ...
 $pdf = new mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf("/path/to/QR_template.pdf");
 ...
```

I tried to get names of all included files by using:

```
 var_dump(get_included_files());
```

but the "pdf" files were not in the array.

Other packages works well but pdftk not. Where is the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem was composer version. Composer self-update solved the problem.

Comment: i have this same isue,but updating the composer haven't helped in my case